# Replace corresponding parts of one array with another array in R

Tags: arrays, r, sorting

I have a array/ named vector that looks like this:

```
d  f  g
1  2  3
```

I want to fill up the empty slots, meaning I want this:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  0  0  1  0  2  3
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this, without having to write loops and conditionals? In my actual problem, instead of abcd as my array names, it's numbers. Not sure if that makes a difference. Figured alphabet is easier to understand for a reproducible example.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a loop for this?  A simple loop could do it very elegantly.

Comment: If this does not represent your actual data, then I think you should change it to represent the real data so as to avoid further questions once answers begin to get posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vector of the final names, `nms` and then create a named vector of zeros from it using `sapply` and replace the elements corresponding to input names with the input values.

```
v <- c(d = 1, f = 2, g = 3) # input

nms <- letters[letters <= max(names(v))] # names on output vector, i.e. letters[1:7]
replace(sapply(nms, function(x) 0), names(v), v) ##
```

giving:

```
a b c d e f g 
0 0 0 1 0 2 3
```

If in your actual vector the names are not letters then just set `nms` yourself.  For example, `nms <- c("dogs", "cats", "d", "elephants", "f", "g")` would work with the same line marked ## above.

**2)** An alternative is to replace the line marked ## above with:

```
unlist(modifyList(as.list(setNames(numeric(length(nms)), nms)), as.list(v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
x <- c(d=1L,f=2L,g=3L);
x;
## d f g
## 1 2 3
```

**Solution 1:** First match new names into `x` and extract values, then replace NAs with zero.

```
x <- setNames(x[match(letters[1:7],names(x))],letters[1:7]);
x[is.na(x)] <- 0L;
x;
## a b c d e f g
## 0 0 0 1 0 2 3
```

**Solution 2:** One-liner, using `nomatch` argument of `match()`.

```
setNames(c(x,0L)[match(letters[1:7],names(x),nomatch=length(x)+1L)],letters[1:7]);
## a b c d e f g
## 0 0 0 1 0 2 3
```